# What is an appropriate deep learning model for three constant repeat number?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I got hype for this deeplearning but not knowing where to start. 
I have background in **python**, **C#** and superficial knowledge of **R**

My friend creating simple games that randomly pick number from constant number.

THE RULES of games is simple:

1. Its have three constant number which is **3**, **6**, **9**.
2. Its randomly pick one from three number above for each day for a week.

This data from years ago until now

```
S,M,T,W,T,F,S
6,3,9,3,3,6,9
9,6,9,9,9,6,9
3,6,9,3,3,6,9
9,3,6,9,6,6,3
6,9,9,6,6,6,3
3,6,6,6,3,3,6
6,9,6,6,9,6,9
9,3,6,9,3,3,6
3,9,6,9,6,9,6
9,3,3,3,6,9,6
6,9,9,6,9,9,3
9,6,9,6,6,3,9
9,9,3,9,9,3,6
6,9,3,9,3,6,6
3,6,9,9,3,9,9
9,9,9,9,6,3,6
6,3,6,6,3,9,3
6,9,9,9,9,3,6
3,6,9,6,9,9,3
3,3,9,9,3,9,3
6,3,6,9,9,6,9
6,3,6,6,6,9,9
6,3,6,6,3,3,9
6,3,6,3,3,3,3
9,9,9,6,9,6,9
9,6,9,9,6,6,9
6,9,9,3,3,6,9
9,3,3,9,3,9,9
9,6,9,9,9,3,9
6,3,9,6,6,6,9
3,3,9,3,9,3,3
6,6,3,9,6,3,6
9,3,3,6,3,6,3
3,9,3,9,3,9,9
6,3,6,3,6,6,6
6,9,6,9,9,6,6
6,3,9,9,9,3,3
9,6,9,3,9,9,3
```

Can we **predict** for next number using **deep learning** or **machine learning** using data above?

or Atleast predict the **pattern** of this simple constant number **based past data**

Any help will be appreciate, Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like there's no pattern, totally random. If that's correct, then an algorithm is doing something wrong if it finds a pattern. No, deep learning should not be able to find a pattern in true randomness. (You can make it overfit, but that will give awful results when you use it on new observations.)

Comment: Where exactly is the 'game' part in this? It's basically a random number generator, and only that.

Comment: @Firebug, well its just have 3 constant number. So we have at least 30% winning.

Comment: @Dave , yup that correct, its randomly choose one of three. can you explain, what overfit. Atleast I dont guess with a luck. I want guess it with back past data.

Comment: @BaraSatria Overfitting would be something like the following to predict digits of pi. First we have 3, then 1. Those add up to 4, which happens to be the next digit. Following this pattern, we guess that the next digit is 1+4=5, but the next digit is 1. However, the nfollowing digit if 5, so we surmise that digits are either the sum of the previous two digits o the digit from two digits ago. Keep applying this logic as you get longer and longer appromimations of pi. You aren't detecting patterns. You're detecting coincidences. That's overfitting.

Comment: (Continued) Applied to this problem, you're doing pretty much the same by trying to detect patterns in randomness. If your random number generator is any good, which it probably is, any apparent pattern is just a coincidence and will not continue. Phrased differently, I challenge you to consistently predict heads vs tails with greater than 50% accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

You say that the numbers are randomly chosen, then you ask for a way to predict them. These are contradictory. If they are random, you can't predict them, by definition. And, if you find some way to predict them, all you've done is to show that the random number generator is faulty.

But, these days, random number generators (or, more properly, pseudo RNGs) are really really good. If you find a way to predict them, that would be huge news (but unlikely).

On the other hand, maybe the data were generated with a really bad RNG. That can happen.

Comment: Hi , Peter.

Thank for replying, please bear with me. I dont have background in statistik or ML or else. 

Yup, its totally random. based RNG

Well, My other friend, He can guessed mostly almost 50% or 60% based past data, he predict like this: its just 3 constant number, that mean we have atleast 30% winning chance, We just need to see past data pattern. But he doing it manually with pen and paper. 

I thought maybe , it can be digitalize. And with more computer power to guess based past data.

I just dont want to guess with blind and pure luck, atleast I have data to check it.

Comment: @BaraSatria Please ask your friend what the pattern is that got him 50-60% accuracy and report back here with his response.

Comment: @BaraSatria Either your friend got incredibly lucky or it is not random. There is no past data pattern - that's what random means.